# Como faço pra importar um arquivo .jar sem usar uma IDE? (Java)

Tags: java

Ex: Tenho um arquivo .jar que preciso importar pra ter acesso a api, como faço isso direto no código? Não sei se fui específico, mas como? (Sem IDE)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar alguns parâmetros na hora da compilação:

```
javac -classpath lib/bar.jar com/example/Foo.java
```

Nesse cenário, sua classe `Foo.java` depende do jar `bar.jar`.

Se você estiver usando um projeto que não utiliza nenhum gerenciador de dependências, fica bem complicado de trabalhar.

Recomendo dar uma estudada no [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) ou no [Gradle](https://www.devmedia.com.br/gerenciamento-de-dependencias-em-java-com-gradle/32797). Eles facilitam quando você tem dependências externas no projeto.

Comment: Além do compilar, só faltou o rodar =D